# Update csv table value except row and column header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file 1 with a table  as following:

| x | customer 1 | customer 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 1 | 23 |
| item2 | 3 | 123 |
| item3 | 123 | 421 |

I would like create copy .csv file 1 as a new .csv file 2 and update all the cell value to a constant except the row and column header.
Also, while the number of rows is constant but the number of columns might change.

| x | customer 1 | customer 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | 5 | 5 |
| item2 | 5 | 5 |
| item3 | 5 | 5 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can `set_index` then assign the value

```
s = df.set_index('x')
s[:] = 5
s.reset_index().to_csv('csv2.csv')
```

Comment: it seems that `s.reset_index().to_csv('csv2.csv')`  will add a new first column index to the original table.
`s = df.set_index('x')
s[:] = 5`
Did the trick for what I need to do. Thanks a lot!